# Error when Using OR operator for typing a property with two interfaces

Tags: angular, typescript, types, interface

I have this ProfessionnalForm interface.
The type of role can be either RecruiterForm or EmployeeForm Interface.
[image]

Can you explain to me why this code break my angular app?
[image]

This is my RecruiterForm Interface:

```
export interface RecruiterForm {
    companyName: string;
    employeesCount: number;
}
```

and my EmployeeForm Interface:

```
export interface EmployeeForm {
    specialization: string;
    skills: string[];
    qualification: string;
    expectedSalary: number;
    //experiences
}
```

Finaly this is my component call with the respective roles
[image]

The solution can be to use any type but its not explicit at all.

Thanks for your help

Comment: I could only guess, because you haven't pasted the code which uses this, but maybe `<app-recruiter>` expects `RecruiterForm` as the `role` parameter?

Comment: Hello @AndreyMarkeev i have edited my question with the call of components.
My roles is present on my component call.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that your `app-recruiter` component's `value` property is of type `RecruiterForm` and you are passing in a variable in your `professional` component (`value?.role`) which is of type `RecruiterForm | EmployeeForm`

You have two options:

- Widen the `app-recruiter` `value` variable to be of type `RecruiterForm | EmployeeForm`
- Ensure that you only pass a variable into the `value` property that is of type `RecruiterForm`

The first option is straightforward if it meets your needs.

The second option can be achieved by filtering `value?.role` into another variable which is strictly only ever type `RecruiterForm` (with something like a [type guard](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html) for example). Alternatively you could reassess the scenario in which `value?.role` is of type `EmployeeForm` and you may find a flaw in your logic which explains why this form may also have been being passed into `app-recruiter` erroneously.